# pip ReadTimeoutError while installing python packages

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am facing this error while trying to install a python package:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url:
>   /packages/f2/12/37c09c37d7ac2bdb6169d5b9409a8e64770a997412edcccc689115d63b97/catboost-0.16-cp36-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
>   (Caused by
>   ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org',
>   port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",))

- My network is not behind any firewall or proxy-server.
- Also i have tried using **--default-timeout=1000** flag in pip command but sometimes it works for me and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Check Your internet connection ??

Comment: I work in an Azure virtual machine so my local internet connection cannot be responsible for this error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, it was fixed when I changed pip to pip3 install because I am using python3

```
pip install <package>
```

make sure it is:

```
pip3 install <package>
```

Comment: It works with the only change done from pip install <package> to pip3 install <package>. It help to save the time.Thanks.